# DateTime picker on same dialog doesn't accept minDate and maxDate

Tags: java, android

I have found a tutorial in Google before for Date and Time picker on same dialog. I've trying to set `minDate` and `maxDate` on the calendar but nothing help. I want to make when user open dialog to choose date default date to be 4 days ahead from current date. For this I've trying to put

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 4);
```

but when I open dialog nothing is changed. The code is a little bit long and I will try to post only what I think is needed. This is `CustomDateTimePicker.java`

```
public void showDialog() {
if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
    if (calendar_date == null)
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

    selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

    //
    datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));


    dialog.show();

    btn_setDate.performClick();
}
}

public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
    this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
}

public void dismissDialog() {
   if (!dialog.isShowing())
      dialog.dismiss();
 }

public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
   if (calendar != null)
    calendar_date = calendar;
}

 public void setDate(Date date) {
   if (date != null) {
    calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_date.setTime(date);
  }
 }

 public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
   if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
        && year < 3000) {
    calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_date.set(year, month, day);

  }

 }

 public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
 if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
        && minute < 60) {
    if (calendar_date == null)
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
            minute);

    is24HourView = true;
  }
}
```

And this is in `MainActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                        Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                        String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                        String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                        int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                        String AM_PM) {
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker)).setText(calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + "-" + (monthNumber+1) + "-" + year
                                    + " " + hour24 + ":" + min);              
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });

    /**
     * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
     * false
     */
    custom.set24HourFormat(false);
    /**
     * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
     */
    custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                       
                    custom.showDialog();
                }

});
```

I believe this is the part which I need to fix but can't get it how exactly.
In case of need here is the full code of `CustomDateTimePicker.java` -> http://pastebin.com/UnifiAWu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 4);
```

You are adding 4 milliseconds to the current time and passing that as the `minDate`. To fix this, you'll have to convert 4 days into milliseconds and add that to your current time.

Comment: I fixed it. It was my fault because I've forget to put `setCalendarViewShown(false);` and on the phone doesn't look quite right.